# Root space of eigenvalues of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry, this is probably a very silly question.  Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear operator.  For each real eigenvalue $\lambda$, define the subspace $E_{\lambda} := \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n: \text{there is a } k \text{ such that }  (A - \lambda \text{Id})^kv = 0\}$.  For a complex eigenvalue $\lambda$, we let $E_{\lambda, \bar{\lambda}}$ be the intersection with $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the union of the root spaces of $\lambda$ and $\bar{\lambda}$, where we consider $A: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$.  We call such a space (any of the two above) a **root space** of $\lambda$

I then define $E^+$ to be the direct sum of all root spaces with $|\lambda| >1$, $E^-$ the direct sum of all root spaces with $|\lambda| < 1$ and $E^0$ the direct sum of all root spaces with $|\lambda| =1 $.

**Question:**  Why do I know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ decomposes as $E^0 + E^+ + E^-$?

Comment: What is the purpose of $E_{\lambda, \overline\lambda}$ in your question?

Comment: I abused notation slightly and was referring to all of the root spaces with the notation $E_\lambda$.  I assumed it was obvious from context.  I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Hint: first prove that $\Bbb C^n$ decomposes in the analogous way—that will be easier.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^n$ is basically just finding the Jordan form of the operator.  I guess my concern is that the basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ that puts the matrix in Jordan form may not be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I can't just directly use that decomposition?